# How do you configure a makefile project that builds against a static library to build against a dynamic library instead?

Tags: c++, dll, makefile, static-libraries, mingw32

I have a C++ project that is required to be built with a static version of Qt. However, QtWebKit will not successfully build statically, though it does build into a dll just fine.

My question is this: how do I tell a Makefile to use dlls instead of static libraries? This seems like it should be a trivial task, though I don't have enough experience with Makefiles to know how to do this. Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Comment: not much as the makefile as it for the compiler - the makefile just builds the compiling command. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a tag. I'm using mingw32 on a windows system. I have access to an Ubuntu box if this is an easier process in a *nix environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `linux` using `GNU Make` environment, the process of linking with static library is

`gcc obj1.o obj2.o staticlib.a -o outfile` //not considering include path for static library

and, linking with a dynamic library is

`gcc obj1.c obj2.c -o outfile -labc` //dynamic library is libabc.so, not considering the path

From the `man` [page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) of `gcc` we can see that,

- -l Search the library named library when linking. The directories searched include several standard system directories plus
  any that you specify with -L
- -L Add directory  to the list of directories to be searched for -l.

Please update your makefile accordingly.

Cheers!!

Comment: using g++ on windows, I have added -l<relative path to library> for all necessary DLLs I built with Qt. Is there something else I'm doing wrong? my command looks like the following: g++ -l..\..\qt\bin\QtCore4.dll -l..\..\qt\bin\QtNetwork4.dll -o .\bin\myapp.exe sourceDir1\*.cc sourceDir2\*.cc sourceDir3\*.cc sourceDir4\*.cc.... the error I am getting is that it can't find Qt types that were built into these Dlls from the header files

Comment: Well it looks like everything is building properly, I'm just not properly linking with the Dll it seems like. I've marked this as the answer since it explains what to change in the makefile.